# repeat same test using robotium

Tags: authentication, screen, robotium

I wanted to know that how can I repeat a test case using robotium?
Example : I have robotium test case for Login screen(Username and password). I want to repeat the same test case 3-4 times with same user. Also I wanted to repeat the same test for different users, lets say, first time "User1", 2nd time "User2 and so on.
I wanted to automate this screen via robotium.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write your own [test suite](http://developer.android.com/reference/junit/framework/TestSuite.html).